# .Net [Windows] TreeView TreeNode does not retain color change after drag and drop

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, treeview

I have a form with 2 tree views, the user can drag and drop a node from one to another. After a node has been dragged and dropped, I change the color[highlight] of the source node in the Drag-Drop event handles.The color of the node changes fine.

But when the users hovers the mouse over the source tree view after that, it flickers and the highlighting I had done disappears, reverting to the original color.

I'm not handling any other event, I don't reload the treeview and I'm not changing the color.

From my understanding of the MSDN documentation, I don't see any Refresh or Repaint type events.

Answer (score 1):

Simply call [TreeView.Invalidate()](http://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&source=web&ct=res&cd=1&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fsystem.windows.forms.treeview.invalidate.aspx&ei=IAe_SISmHI--0gXLyohj&usg=AFQjCNFXA21Y-krL3TatTQBsUN3rb6kNKQ&sig2=SKScXy0bQ17dRS0qZiuzaA) method to force tree view to repaint.